# crystal report object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: object, crystal-reports, nullreferenceexception

I have crystal reports that keeps saying this error:

{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Stacktrace:

```
at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageControl.OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseMove(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)
   at System.Windows.Window.Show()
   at System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()
   at ADR.Forms.GALReport.GuardianAdLitemReport.btnPreviewReport() in C:\Users\user\Development\ProjectADR\ADR\Forms\CaseCoordinatorReports\GALReport\GuardianAdLitemReport.xaml.cs:line 527
   at ADR.Forms.GALReport.GuardianAdLitemReport.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\user\Development\ProjectADR\ADR\Forms\CaseCoordinatorReports\GALReport\GuardianAdLitemReport.xaml.cs:line 90
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at ADR.Program.Main() in C:\Users\user\Development\ProjectADR\ADR\Program.cs:line 57
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Sometimes it loads, most of the time it says that. It seems to say that alternately. Like if I rerun the report, it loads the report as what is expected then does not on the second run. What is wrong?

it stops in this code:
 crview.ShowDialog();

To give you background, I am using dataset source the same with otehr reports. but other reports are not havign this kind of problem. Anyone who can tell me? thanks.

Comment: Yes I did instantiate the crview like this: CrystalReportViewerUC crview = new CrystalReportViewerUC();
                        crview.SetReportPathFile(reportPath);
                        crview.BuildDataTable(ds, dsName); and tried to see all have values and not null

Comment: I'm having the same problems. Did you solved this already?

Comment: Sorry I haven't. I just let it be that way. anyway in deployed / installed app, it doesn't happen. Only in debug/runtime on my pc when I run it using VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this is an older thread, here is how I solved my issue.

I found that I had a text box with a formula that was beyond the bounds of the page. So it was causing a new page to be created with a NULL string. The formula was crashing and causing the following error:

System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I was only seeing this once in a while because the returned value sometimes caused the TextObject to grow.

To solve this

- I can fix the formula to handle NULLs, though it would still cause the extra blank page
- Re-position the text box within the bounds of my page size and set CanGrow to False.

I opted for both because a user could unintentionally cause blank pages by selecting a smaller paper size from their printer.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to Crystal Reports for Visual Studio re-distributable version 13_0_3 solved this issue for me.

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
I had this problem for years!
I work with DataSet as reportSource. Finally, after trying every solution I could find on forums, I found the answer myself: the DataSet contained null values, so I just had to make the DataSet string fields DefaultValue: " " instead of DBNull... dead simple, yet effective.

Hope this helps.